# How can I find a protein sequence from a FASTA file using perl?

Tags: regex, perl, bioinformatics, protein-database

So I have an exercise in which I have to print the three first lines of a fasta file as well as the protein sequence. I have tried to run a script I wrote, but cygwin doesnt seem to print the sequence out. My code is as follows:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
open (IN,'P30988.txt');
while (<IN>) {
    if($_=~ m/^ID/) {
        print $_ ;
    }
    if($_=~ m/^AC/) {
        print $_ ;
    }
    if ($_=~ m/^SQ/) {
        print $_;
    }
    if ($_=~ m/\^s+(\w+)/) { #this is the part I have trouble with
        $a.=$1;
        $a=~s/\s//g; #this is for removing the spaces inside the sequence
        print $a;
    }
```

The fast file looks like this:

```
SQ   SEQUENCE   474 AA;  55345 MW;  0D9FA81230B282D9 CRC64;
     MRFTFTSRCL ALFLLLNHPT PILPAFSNQT YPTIEPKPFL YVVGRKKMMD AQYKCYDRMQ
     QLPAYQGEGP YCNRTWDGWL CWDDTPAGVL SYQFCPDYFP DFDPSEKVTK YCDEKGVWFK
     HPENNRTWSN YTMCNAFTPE KLKNAYVLYY LAIVGHSLSI FTLVISLGIF VFFRSLGCQR
     VTLHKNMFLT YILNSMIIII HLVEVVPNGE LVRRDPVSCK ILHFFHQYMM ACNYFWMLCE
     GIYLHTLIVV AVFTEKQRLR WYYLLGWGFP LVPTTIHAIT RAVYFNDNCW LSVETHLLYI
     IHGPVMAALV VNFFFLLNIV RVLVTKMRET HEAESHMYLK AVKATMILVP LLGIQFVVFP
     WRPSNKMLGK IYDYVMHSLI HFQGFFVATI YCFCNNEVQT TVKRQWAQFK IQWNQRWGRR
     PSNRSARAAA AAAEAGDIPI YICHQELRNE PANNQGEESA EIIPLNIIEQ ESSA
//
```

To match the sequence I used the fact that each line starts with several spaces and then its only letters. It doesnt seem to do the trick regarding cygwin. Here is the link for the sequence https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P30988.txt

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Jiust saying you are "having trouble" doesn't help us root-cause the issue. Show us some example input. Include the output you are currently getting along with what you expect.

Comment: @pmqs youre right. The output im getting are the first three lines of the file which I want and the SQ line but without the actual sequence. I want the whole sequence and the line I commented on in my code is supposed to match the sequence but it doesnt seem to

Comment: That gives us a better idea of the problem, but it isn't enough for us to help you. Please edit the question to add an example of the input data.

Comment: I made an edit to give everyone a look regarding the part I want printed out

Comment: They are multiple lines yes

Comment: They are multiple lines yes

Comment: It is impossible for us to know where the lines end with the formatting. Please reformat by putting the text into a code block so we can see the individual lines.

Alternatively provide a link to an example file that is publicly available.

Comment: I edited in a link for the flat file

Comment: The shebang is wrong. use `#!/usr/bin/perl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
if ($_=~ m/\^s+(\w+)/) { #this is the part I have trouble with
```

You have the backslash in the wrong place in this part `\^s+`. You are actually escaping the `^`. The line in your code should be

```
if ($_=~ m/^\s+(\w+)/) { #this is the part I have trouble with
```

I'd write that block of code like this

```
if ($_=~ m/^\s/) { 
    s/\s+//g; #this is for removing the spaces inside the sequence
    print $_;
}
```